Libreoffice not respecting docxjs auto table width
It's like the title states.
If I omit the table width, it ends up with 0, and doesn't show up at all.
The only way to make it show up at all is by doing:
width: {
  size: 100,
  type: Docx.WidthType.PERCENTAGE
}

which is not desirable.
If I open the generated document up with Onlyoffice or MS Word, it renders correctly.
If I then resave the file with MS Word, it renders properly in Libreoffice as well.
Resaving the document in MS Word is not really and option since I'm generating the docs on my backend, and then using Libreoffice to turn them to PDFs, so I need them to be right from the get go. I did some document.xml inspecting, but wasn't able to pinpoint the reason for Libreoffice choking.
Does anyone know of a workaround, or a way to fix the document up post generation?
Docx version: 8.5.0
Libreoffice version: 24.8.0.3
